# Detecting string within URL stored in variable

Tags: javascript

I've been writing an app that utilizes the following code to detect if there is a -size parameter within the URL that's stored in the `bgimg` variable.

Reason being there's lots of null values that are returned and since it's looking for the size parameter, oftentimes the code will get stuck in a loop of errors saying it cannot read property indexOf null.

The ultimate goal is to dynamically replace the bgimg variable when it's null.

I did some research and the easiest solution I found was using indexOf but whenever bgimg.indexOf("-size") is null it doesn't seem to accept it.

---

```
var bgimg = t[e]['art'];
if(bgimg.indexOf("-size") != null){
    var bgimg = bgimg.replace('-size','-newsizePXxPX');
    var art = $('.art').css('background-image', 'url(' + bgimg + ')');
}
else
{
    var bgimg = "http://artfillerhere.jpg";
    var art = $('.art').css('background-image', 'url(' + bgimg + ')');  
}
```

Any sort of help or advice on how to fix this dilemma would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If the problem is that `bgimg` is null, then check `if( bgimg !== null )`.

Comment: @Juhana or even just `if (!bgimg)`

Comment: @Teemu here's an example: https://urlsdn.co/artworks-000072992430-cmqhvh-sizehere.jpg

the url above is an edited. but the issue is I'm looking for the specific part of the URL that being "-sizehere" in the URL. If it's true than I want to run the first argument, if it's false than I want to just replace the null value all together with a different value.

Comment: @Juhana the bgimg variable definitely does return null sometimes, but I think it would be more logical to look for the actual size parameter in the variable itself in my scenario. I could kill two birds with one stone that way.

Comment: Well, you couldn't because `null` doesn't have an `.indexOf` method so you can't get around checking for null at some point.

Comment: @Juhana that makes sense.. thank you. I guess my best bet is to use your suggested approach!

Comment: indexOf does not return null

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you do `bgimg && bgimg.indexOf("-size") != -1`. `.indexOf()` returns `-1` if string is not found or otherwise the index of the found string.

```
var bgimg = t[e]['art'];
if(bgimg && bgimg.indexOf("-size") != -1){
    var bgimg = bgimg.replace('-size','-newsizePXxPX');
    var art = $('.art').css('background-image', 'url(' + bgimg + ')');
}
else
{
    var bgimg = "http://artfillerhere.jpg";
    var art = $('.art').css('background-image', 'url(' + bgimg + ')');  
}
```